# Send mail using an email account created on Hostinger (PHP)

Tags: email, phpmailer

I am sending an email through PHPMailer, the code is hosted on hostinger's hpanel and I am using an email I created on the hpanel. After running the code, I get no errors, and no feedback on whether the mail has been sent, it just doesn't show anything.

Please help me I currently don't know what to do.

```
        require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        try
        {
            $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
            
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.titan.email';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'admin@hostinger.com';
            $mail->Password = 'password';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';
            $mail->Port = 465;

            $mail->setFrom('admin@hostinger.com', 'Hostinger');
            $mail->addAddress($email, $username);
            $mail->addReplyTo('admin@hostinger.com', 'For any Information');
            $mail->addCC('admin@hostinger.com');
            
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Sending message';
            $mail->Body    = $message;
            $mail->AltBody = "Hello there";

            $mail->send();

            echo "Sent";
        }
        catch (Exception $eax) 
        {
            echo 'EMAIL SENDING FAILED. INFO: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, that will be a fatal error that should appear in your logs, so check in there. My guess would be that you have no `use` statements to import PHPMailer into your namespace, so you're getting a fatal error when trying to create the PHPMailer instance.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I imported PHPMailer into my namespace, I just didn't indicate it on the code. I checked my error log, there was nothing. But when I use the wrong password it shows me an authentication error, I still don't have an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: `SMTPSecure` should be `ssl` not `SSL`, and that may cause a connection failure.

Comment: Okay, I will do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to Use
$mail->isSMTP();

Comment $mail->isSMTP();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right smtp host:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

My mail server is not smtp.hostinger.com but titan (on Hostinger premium web hosting):

```
//$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.titan.email';
$mail->Port = 465;
```